# Can the logic operators OR, AND, IF-THEN, NOT be simplified to NOT(x OR y)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have been bashing my head against this problem for a few days now and am curious what others think. I know that all circuits can be built using AND gates and OR gates, so it seems intuitive that the set of logic operators could be simplified to $\lnot(x\lor y)$, but every time I construct the truth tables for it, I end up needing another negation, or to use an operator more than once, breaking my proof.

The exact sentence I am agonizing over is:

> Prove or disprove that $\{M,\phi,\lnot,\lor,\land,\Rightarrow\}$ can be reduced to $\{M,\phi,\nabla\}$, where $x\nabla y$ is equivalent to $\lnot(x\lor y)$.

Comment: Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOR_logic ?

Comment: Yes, they can. See [NOR logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOR_logic) and the NOR examples [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness#Examples).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... what do you mean by "using an operator more than once" breaking your proof? Nowhere does it require that you not use an operator more than once. Also, AND and OR gates aren't enough, to my knowledge - you can't make a NOT out of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOT(x OR y) is certainly enough for what I think you're asking. Per my comment, I'm not sure what you mean by "using an operator more than once" - if we're not allowed to use NOT(x OR y) more than once, we certainly can't build anything more complicated. But if we can use it freely, we can build anything we like. For example, NOT(x OR x) is equivalent to NOT(x). Once we have NOT, we can make AND by taking NOT(NOT(x) OR NOT(y)). AND and NOT are enough to build everything else. AND and OR are not - both are always true when all of their inputs are true, so there's no way to construct a NOT from just AND and OR.

Comment: Thanks Reese, I had to get some clarification on the question of if I was allowed to use the operators more than once, and once that was cleared up, I was able to solve the problem. Thank you for your answer, it helped verify my logic and got me started thinking in the correct way!